# Softphone for 64-bit Windows 7 to make SIP calls without registering with a SIP proxy?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, voip, sip

We have test tools that require us to call SIP addresses like `localhost:5061`.

I used to use SJPhone on Windows XP, and an older version of X-lite, which both worked fine, and didn't require the SIP phone to be registered with a SIP proxy.

I have just upgraded to Windows 7 and SJPhone doesn't seem to work any more (see forum [here](http://community.plus.net/forum/index.php/topic,85221.0.html) for others with the problem) - it says "No sound input device / No sound output device" at startup.

I have tried a range of other softphones (X-lite 3, X-lite 4, Zoiper, 3CX), but I can't seem to find any that will install on Windows 7 and will let me call a SIP address like `localhost:5061`.  It might be that I just don't know how to configure these phones to do it...

**Update:** I didn't make any changes but SJPhone started working recently on my Windows 7 machine.  I had definitely tried rebooting before, so I don't think that was the reason.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Blink http://icanblink.com/ will do exactly what you want.

I used it for testing in the way you mentioned when I wanted to get user@domain.com type SIP addresses working on my Freeswitch server.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Ekiga softphone from http://www.ekiga.org/ supports this on Windows 7.  You don’t need to register with this phone, and can call an arbitrary SIP server using the syntax:

```
sip:<user>@<servername>
```

I've also heard that a good workaround is to install Virtual Server on your Windows 7 box, and run SJPhone inside an XP virtual machine.